# Tengo el problema de que al crear un nuevo proyecto en visual estudio 2022, y al abrirlo solo me muestra la solución indicando (0 proyectos)

Tags: visual-studio

[image: explorador de soluciones]

Esta es lo que me sale al abrir el proyecto nuevo, ya sea de cualquier tipo

Comment: tengo el mismo problema, hice lo recomendado y no se solucionó, si me colaboran?

Comment: Como última opcion, lo que hice fue formatear mi PC eso solucionó el problema

Answer (score 0):

Que tal yo tenia un problema similar lo que hice fue ir al visual studio installer > modificar >componentes individuales> plantillas de proyecto y de elmento de .NET.
Instalarlo y reiniciar y con eso se arreglo

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda